# Can I prevent auto-conversion of text to emoji in a Telegram bot?

Tags: emoji, telegram-bot

I'm building a Telegram bot, in which the user sends messages, which are later posted to another website. The text must be sent precisely as the user writes it, but the desktop Telegram app auto-converts some strings to emojis. For example, `:|` is auto-converted to , and I really don't want this. It is good and fun for conversations between humans, but not for this bot, where precision is important. It must stay as `:|`.

I'm talking about messages sent by the user to the bot.

Can I prevent this? I can disable this auto-conversion in my desktop app, but that would only affect myself, and I'd really prefer not to have to instruct the bot users to change their settings, but to have it done it automatically for the chat with the bot. (I don't care about auto-conversion in other conversations that they have.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use Telegram Desktop, it is a “feature” of this client.

You can use `` ` `` or ```` ``` ```` between text to send `<code>` markup, which won't auto replace by client.

Comment: But will this affect messages sent by the user or by the bot? I need this for messages sent by the user. The conversion happens client-side, and by the time they arrive to the bot they are already converted.